# How can I make an animation in Unity play just once and then switch back to another animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d game in Unity, and for the main character I have created 4 animations; up, down, left, and right. To do this I just made the animation and trigger them with a line of code like this:

```
anim.SetBool ("movingUp", true);
```

which would happen when the up key is pressed. This type of animation is easy to deal with because it is not based on time, but how long the player wants the character to be in that state. I am now trying to add an animation that is triggered when the character collides with another game object. I am not sure how to make it so the animation will play just one time and then go back to the other animation. Is there a way to trigger an animation to play just once in Unity?

Comment: Think about your animations as states, and your animation controller as a state machine. I'd make an idle animation and have that be the entry. Have your other animations work off that and then fallback to the default(idle) anim based on logic. You can set the properties for each animation by clicking on it. They pop up in the inspector

Comment: @mtrueblood the character will never be in an idle state and this doesnt really answer my question I already understand how to work with animations I have them working, I just don't now how to make the animation play only once. You cannot logic your way through that with states because the character is in the state where it hits the game object for a split second, not long enough to play the animation, so how do you play the animation until it's complete is what i am asking

Comment: You should provide more detail, my comment was only meant asa a general comment since I wasn't sure exactly what your issue was. You can set a fixed duration for the animation and turn off looping from the animator panel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you don't have to code your own controller, Unity already has that one and [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation) is the link to official Unity tutorials how to use it. What you need is to `fire off a trigger` just like you did upon `collision` and check `has exit time` on that animation in the controller. After that you just guide the state back to the animation you want it to go back to. Again, accurate and thorough tutorials are found online on the term `Unity Mecanim how to` or `Animations in Unity` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Select the animation in Assets. Have you unchecked "Loop Time"? This is what solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

MAke an animator controller and add the 4 animations into it. then make a transition between them with the Boolean. Are you doing this as an automatic animation without triggering it?